# Referencing a specific public_ip created in a loop with terraform

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machine, terraform

I cant properly reference the first azure public ip created with terraform into a network security group created with same terraform script.

I tried various approach for this line to be ok:

```
source_address_prefix      = "${(count.index == 0 ? var.incoming_ip : azurerm_public_ip.test.0.)}"
```

I tried:

```
azurerm_public_ip.test.0.name
azurerm_public_ip.test.0.ip_adress
azurerm_public_ip.test[0]
```

But I get an error while deploying, it seems to pass null or a string to the script, instead of the public_ip of ther first instance created with count.index being 0.

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "test" {
 name                         = "publicIP-${count.index}"
 location                     = "${var.regions[count.index]}"
 resource_group_name          = "${element(azurerm_resource_group.test.*.name, count.index)}"
 allocation_method            = "Static"
 count                        = "${length(var.regions)}"
 }

 resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "test" {
    name                = "${var.nameid[count.index]}"
    count               = "${length(var.regions)}"
    location            = "${var.regions[count.index]}"
    resource_group_name = "${element(azurerm_resource_group.test.*.name, count.index)}"

    security_rule {
        name                       = "SSH"
        priority                   = 1001
        direction                  = "Inbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "22"
        source_address_prefix      = "${var.incoming_ip}"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }

    security_rule {
        name                       = "curl"
        priority                   = 1002
        direction                  = "Inbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "${(count.index == 0 ? 8888 : 7777)}"
        source_address_prefix      = "${(count.index == 0 ? var.incoming_ip : azurerm_public_ip.test.0.)}"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }
}
```

I am expecting this line:

```
source_address_prefix      = "${(count.index == 0 ? var.incoming_ip : azurerm_public_ip.test.0.name)}"
```

to behave in that way:

if count.index == 0 then value of var.incoming_ip else value of the azure public ip created at index 0.

Comment: The solution is to reference it as: element(azurerm_public_ip.test.*.ip_address, 0)

Comment: You can add an answer to show the solution for the community who is looking for it.

Comment: Do you try my solution? I think it's a better one format as you want.

Comment: I seem to recall trying it. Ill retry later. thx

Comment: OK, when you try and it really works for you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Do you try the solution? Or you just want to use the way that you find out? I didn't see any updates.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax did the trick:

```
source_address_prefix      = "${(count.index == 0 ? var.incoming_ip : element(azurerm_public_ip.test.*.ip_address, 0))}"
```